# php - why post request is taking too much time?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Using php-mysql, I am fetching data, pushing it into an array. An array consists of 486 records. It's an associative array with 7 column for each record.

When there is a GET request, it works fine. Getting data, binding it to table, chart and dropdown. Everything works fine.

I need to populate dropdown based on selection of another dropdown. And in that case I am making a POST request. And searching in the same array of 486 records.

```
    $temp           = Array();
    $teamSelectData = Array();

    foreach ($allBookingsData as $key => $value) {
        if($value['PDG'] == $passedPDG){
            array_push($temp, $value["Team_Name"]);       
        }
    }

    $tempTeam = array_iunique($temp);
    foreach ($tempTeam as $key => $value) {
        array_push($teamSelectData, Array(
            'name'  => $value,
            'value' => $key,
            'title' => $value
        ));
    }

    $returnArray['TeamSelectData'] = $teamSelectData;

// get unique items from array
function array_iunique($array) { 
    $upper = array_map('strtolower', $array); 
    return array_intersect_key($array, array_unique($upper)); 
}
```

I couldn't able to figure out why is it taking too much time to execute. The comparison `if($value['PDG'] == $passedPDG)` is the issue or the function `array_iunique`. And the same way I am populating dropdown for PDG. Based on a selection of PDG, I need to fill dropdown of Team.

**How to make this function efficient ?**

Comment: Can you define "too long"?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference whether it's a GET or POST. But GET requests can use the browser cache, so maybe it's not being sent to the server at all.

Comment: Looping over 486 records shouldn't take much time unless your server is very overloaded.

Comment: Server is not overloaded for other requests. It takes 4-5 seconds to fill dropdown of Team. And it's being filled only after change in PDG dropdown which is being filled by GET request.